# Is there a logging tool to find the process(es) that use resources in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, resource-monitor

I have got the following scenario:

On Windows 7 64 bit, my programs collect data from external sources and store them to the computer's second hard disk (not the boot disk). The amount of data is so large, that they nearly max out the disk's writing capacity.

Now, normally that's not a problem (and running on Windows XP it wasn't either). But once in a while, some other process seems to start automatically and hooks some resource in a way that my programs lose data big time.

Unfortunately I have been unable to find out exactly when this happens. It's possible that everything runs fine for hours and then suddenly the problem occurs. Since nobody is sitting there watching it, I don't know what exactly is happening, only when it happened (up to the second).

I have disabled all power saving options, the screen saver, the virus scanner, windows update and everything else I could think of (though any additional hints are welcome).

Now I am looking for a tool that can help me. It ideally should log the use of system resources and give me a list of which process uses what at which time.

I tried the Windows resource monitor, but can't figure out how to save the data in a form that would allow me to get the required information.
I know Process Monitor, but not good enough to know whether it has that option, but will check it out further.

Any other hints?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Performance Monitor may be what you want. It is built-in and you can configure it to capture whatever you want.

There are a couple of example configurations done for you but I recommend working out exactly what you want to track, set up a custom data collector set for that. When you run the collector set, it produces a report which you can then view.

Issues you may need to look for will most likely relate to one or more of: CPU, disk utilisation and memory utilisation.